# JavaCv/OpenCv error: what does it mean?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, runtime-error

I'm using [JavaCv](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) with [OpenCv 2.3](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) from Java (on Windows). Occasionally something goes wrong, and OpenCv throws an error, something like:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (unrecognized or unsupported array type) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 995

With the following Java stacktrace:

```
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage(Native Method)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage$ReleaseDeallocator.deallocate(opencv_core.java:492)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer$DeallocatorReference.clear(Pointer.java:127)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:171)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:61)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSize.allocate(Native Method)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSize.<init>(opencv_core.java:2152)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvSize(opencv_core.java:2170)
```

I.e. it occurs when I try to deallocate an image. Since my knowledge of C++ and OpenCv internals is, well, not much, I thought I'd ask here.

What does the error message mean? Is there anything that could cause then to happen while releasing an IplImage?

---

*Meta: the question previously also asked about catching/skipping a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error dialogue. However, I realised I was asking two completely different questions, and migrated that part to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982426/execution-halts-on-microsoft-visual-c-runtime-error-popup) question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allocate your `IplImage` using `IplImage.create()`, you should not call `cvReleaseImage()` manually on it. <- This is most likely the cause of the error. Either call `IplImage.release()` or let the garbage collector deallocate it for you, at some point in the future...